# Angular and digest auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/guide/basic-digest/) with my node.js server.

I have an RESTFull api and want to implement digest auth so that my user can then interact with my API.

In Angular, using $resource, how can I implement the digest auth process? I see that using username, realm and password I must compute a "nonce" using MD5...

If you already did that, I would be happy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

your can put the token in the http header if user login success.
In angularjs you can do this:

```
//put the user token to the default http request headers after user login.
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['API-Token'] = 'vy4eUCqpQmGoeWsnHKwCQw'; 

//create service and push the token to the request headers.
angular.module('usersService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('User', function($resource, api-token) {
        var User = $resource('http://api.test.com\\:8080/1.0/users', { }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: { 'API-Token': api-token }
            }
        });
        return User
    });
```